# lodash groupby uses string key instead of number

Tags: javascript, lodash

When using `groupby` from lodash the key for each group assumes a string instead of its original type

example:

```
let p1 = { age: 50 };
let p2 = { age: 130 };
let p3 = { age: 25 };
let groups = _.groupBy([p1, p2, p3], (p: any) => p.age);
let sortedKeys = _.keys(groups).sort();
for (let key of sortedKeys) {      
  console.log(key);
}
```

output:

> 130 string
>
> 25 string
>
> 50 string

I know I can fix this by modifying sort()

```
_.keys(groups).sort((k1:any, k2:any) => { return k1-k2; });
```

but shouldnt the original type (in this example `number`) of the `groupby` key be maintained ?

Comment: Because object keys are strings

Comment: Why exactly do you expect to happen? Are you trying to organize an objects keys by a sort? Object key order is not guaranteed and never will be.

Comment: trying to groupby a number then sort by that grouping. not expecting the grouping to do the sorting but i expected the type of the groupby to be preserved

Comment: Yeah as you've mentioned lodash's function is not going to preserve the type. You can have whole numbers as keys though if you want to write your own function

Comment: anyone figured out how to preserve the key as int yet? I am having the same issue. Don't care for sorting. But my output needs to have the keys as integers and not strings.

Answer (score 2):

This has been captured in the comments, but I think it should be the answer: object keys are strings! Lodash cannot change that, so providing a custom comparator to `.sort` is necessary and correct.

As a side note, lodash does provide a numeric dictionary type in typescript, but that is really just a hint that the keys can be *parsed* as numbers. If you check the type of the keys of a numeric dictionary, typescript will (correctly) tell you that they are strings:

```
const a: _.NumericDictionary<string> = {};
const keys = Object.keys(a); // string[]   
keys[0] * 10; // does not compile
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why lodash `groupBy` doesn't support `number` or `Symbol` keys. It seems feasible to define a generic `KeyType` based on the key-selector function (or even property name). Perhaps it's just waiting for someone to PR a better type definition to `@types/lodash`.

In the mean-time, I wrote this for my project (I only needed the function variant):

```
const groupByNumber = <T>(data: T[], keySelector: ((k: T) => number)): Record<number, T[]> => {
  const result: Record<number, T[]> = {}

  for (const datum of data) {
    const key = keySelector(datum)
    if (!(key in result)) {
      result[key] = [datum]
    } else {
      result[key].push(datum)
    }
  }

  return result
}
```

You won't be able to chain, but you can nest:

```
const data = mapValues(groupByNumber(detections, d => d.hour), ds => ds.length)
```

I'm sure it can be improved, but it's better than nothing, & hopefully it prompts more discussion & iteration :)